# Recommend books on mechanics, motion and it's laws

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, resource-recommendations

I want a book that discuss all these things practically. I don't require it for any exam. Just for applying it confidently anywhere (want to Analyse fluids,thermo etc.) Want a book that explain how to apply these in real world considering every aspect(considering real world problem s). Discusses the ideas behind these laws. builds confidence in these laws.

Comment: hi there, do you want an abstract/analytic treatment? (e.g [Arnold. Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Classical-Mechanics-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387968903), [Lanczos. The Variational Principles of Mechanics](http://www.amazon.com/Variational-Principles-Mechanics-Dover-Physics/dp/0486650677), etc.. ). For an approach which is not such abstract sth like [Haliday-Resnick Fundamentals of Physics](http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Physics-David-Halliday/dp/111823071X)

Comment: all previous books are older but classic, there are more modern approaches (havent; read it myself) [A Modern Approach to Classical Mechanics](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/5144)

Comment: plus i would recommend some books about the historical development of mechanics (or physics in general), as these provide perspective and (many times) more clear flow and evolution of the ideas and methods (**and why** they were developed)

Comment: a textbook usually presents the already formulated ideas and methods in condenced (and/or abstract) form, (usualy) taking away the context (and process) into which these methods were developed and which conditions triggered this development.

Comment: So which book Mr nikos you recommend me and why ?a mathematical treatment is must plus some real world discussion is what I require. I just want to analyze fluids mechanics ,thermo ,engines etc on my own (for fun) and I believe for this I require this.what do you think

Comment: sure you know better what you need, i already added a couple of references (both analytic and bare-bones) all considered classic and good, you can check those (some are available online as pdfs) or check more modern approaches

Comment: here check this also [Solved problems in classical mechanics](http://www.scielo.org.za/scielo.php?pid=S0038-23532012000200007&script=sci_arttext) for practical problem solving methodology